# How to add any specific object's page layout in package.xml?

Tags: page-layout, package.xml

I am trying below code in `package.xml`.

```
<types>
    <members>Quote Layout</members>
    <name>Layout</name>
</types>
```

but got error as below.

> == WARNING: The following metadata isn’t in your org. If it’s not new, someone deleted it from the org. Entity of type 'Layout' named
>   'Quote Layout' cannot be found sfdx force:source:retrieve
>   --manifest g:\My Drive\SB\manifest\package.xml ended with
>   exit code 0

**The page layout is present in org.**

Please point out what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try with:

```
<types>
    <members>Quote-Quote Layout</members>
    <name>Layout</name>
</types>
```

For any unpackaged object and page layout format will be

```
<Object Name>-<Layout Name>
```

For object and pagelayout which has namespace format look like

```
<namespace>__<Object Name>-<namespace>__<Layout Name>
```

You can refer [Layout metadata](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_layouts.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the name of that page layout is in your org. It looks like there is not page layout with the name "Quote Layout". Make sure that this is not the case. It is good to explicitly named your page layout. You can use the ObjectName.PagelayoutName

```
<types>
    <members>ObjectName.PagelayoutName</members>
    <name>Layout</name>
</types>
```

**First** .- Make sure that there is a page layout with that name.
If there is not one.... there is why you are getting that error.

**Second** . -Try to use the **ObjectName.PagelayoutName** member.